# MSVCP90.DLL is missing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0 and created a simple command line C++ project (`.EXE` file). When I'm trying to execute it an error modal windows is saying: "The program can't start because MSVCP90.DLL is missing from your computer".

The file exists on the machine at `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcp90.dll`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is that directory in your system path? Apps won't scan your entire drive to find a .dll. They'll scan the system path and stop after that. Either add that dir to your path, or copy the .dll into a directory that IS in the path (e.g. \windows\system32).

Comment: By "system path" you mean `PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Yes.            and some junk to make this comment an acceptable length.